# WordPress 3.0 & nginx - permalink, 404 problem

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I've installed nginx, FastCGI and PHP on my server. WordPress 3.0 installed after a bit of a monster battle, but it's installed and working well.

However, when I change the permalink settings to anything other than default, I get 404 errors on every post, article and page.

I understand that this is something to do with nginx not supporting .htaccess and WordPress getting confused with where to go when a page is requsted.

I've tried a few rewrites in the nginx conf files and even the nginx compatibility plugin; neither have worked. With one rewrite I managed to stop the 404 errors, but instead of WordPress finding the post I was after I merely got my PHP confirmation page. Bah.

Forums are littered with people with similar issues. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress 3.0 conversion of .htaccess to nginx rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865690/wordpress-3-0-conversion-of-htaccess-to-nginx-rewrite-rules)

Comment: Everything linked via that post does not work.

Answer (score 17):

On your location / block,

add this and remove any non-specific rewrite rules:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Comment: This worked without problems, and it's the recommended solution according to the nginx official wiki.

Comment: Here is the key:  It has to be your **/** directory.

If you put it in your /blog directory or anywhere else you will get 404 errors still.

Comment: wiredniko - Put before the index.php your directory location. In your case /index.php would turn to /blog/index.php .

Answer (score 6):

If wordpress is on another directory besides the root, instead of having

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/wordpress/(.+)$ /wordpress/index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

You can have:

```
location /wordpress {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}
```

This page has exactly the same concept. I should have read and tried it first: [nginx rewrite rule under a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876462/nginx-rewrite-rule-under-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 5):

After much pain:

```
# if filename doesn't exist, take the request and pass to wordpress as a paramater
         if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/wordpress/(.+)$ /wordpress/index.php?q=$1 last;
         }
```

If the requested file does not exist, pass it to index.php. It's a bit slow and I think I might try and not use a query, but it does work... :)

Comment: Glad to hear you made a breakthrough! Sorry @Taffy, I've no experience with nginx, but I'll always do my best to help ;)

Comment: You don't need to use a rewrite search; [see the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876462/nginx-rewrite-rule-under-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [nginx Compatibility plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-compatibility/)?

Plus ElasticDog seems to provide a fairly [concise article on getting WP working with nginx](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/) - which includes getting pretty permalinks to work.

Here's another article that seems to deal specifically with [nginx rewrite rules for WordPress](http://www.romej.com/archives/515/nginx-rewrite-rules-for-wordpress-redux).

Comment: Yes, tired the plugin - doesn't work. I also have followed ElasticDog's tutorial, I'm using much of his config now.

I've also followed http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Nginx and understand most of it (I think!) but again, same problem.

Whenever I change the permalinks to anything other than default and try to access a post, article or page I get the "No input file specified." error.

I assume that WordPress (and the rewrites) are failing to tell WordPress what to do, but I'm getting nowhere... :(

Comment: The plugin does work, it's just that there's another thing you need to do: http://piran.com.au/2011/10/nginx-and-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: @Rich your link is now a 404, which is why it's good to excerpt important info into an edit on the answer, or your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This was how I solved my permalinks in my wordpress blogs in dreamhost.

Inside the folder `/home/ftpusername/nginx/example.com/` (if you don't have it, create it)

created the file
**nginx.conf** with the following content

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

restarted the nginx
**/etc/init.d/nginx reload**

**Some notes:**
ftpusername and example.com MUST be changed according to your system.

That was it!
Good luck for u all.

Answer (score 0):

this does not work if you are using location other than / like:

~ .php$, what i meant to say that pretty link will work but your graphics will be all over the place. so what you need is exactly stated below.

http://www.pearlin.info

```
  location ~ \.php$



   {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following..

in the folder 
/home/userrunningnginx/nginx/domain.com

I have:

default.conf (file)

```
include /home/neukbaarofnietps/nginx/neukbaarofniet.com/drop;
```

drop (file)

```
# Rather than just denying .ht* in the config, why not deny
# access to all .invisible files
location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
```

nginx.conf (file)

```
location / {
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

}

WORDPRESS-NGINX.CONF (file)

```
 #######################
# WP Super Cache

# if the requested file exists, return it immediately
if (-f $request_filename) {
  break;
}

set $supercache_file '';
set $supercache_uri $request_uri;

if ($request_method = POST) {
  set $supercache_uri '';
}

# Using pretty permalinks, so bypass the cache for any query string
if ($query_string) {
set $supercache_uri '';
}

if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author_|wordpress|wp-postpass_" ) {
set $supercache_uri '';
}

# if we haven't bypassed the cache, specify our supercache file
if ($supercache_uri ~ ^(.+)$) {
set $supercache_file /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host$1/index.html;
}

# only rewrite to the supercache file if it actually exists
if (-f $document_root$supercache_file) {
rewrite ^(.*)$ $supercache_file break;
}

# all other requests go to Wordpress
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this block to your nginx.conf should solve the issue:

```
     if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/wordpress_dir/(.+)$ /wordpress_dir/index.php?q=$1 last;
     }
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck.